# Fibonacci code gives the incorrect output

Tags: javascript

I want to write the Fibonacci code but this will display only the `n` value and value of a at first time only

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  var a = 0;
  var b = 1;
  Numberi;
  console.log((n));

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    console.log(a + " ");
    n = a + b;
    a = b;
    b = n;

  }
}

fibonacci(10);
```

Comment: you dont return anything

Comment: i use console.log to see the result

Comment: "Numberi not defined"

Comment: my bad , it was Number  instead of integer but still not working

Comment: You are overwriting `n`, and so making the loop shorter than intended. You should really take the habit of declaring variables with `let`, `const` or `var` and not have implicitly defined globals. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: That also makes no sense.

Comment: @trincot ok , thanks man , now the problem has been solved

Answer (score 1):

Try something like

```js
function fibonacci(n) {
  let i = 0;
    
  let x = 1;
  if ( i++ < n ) console.log(x);
  
  let y = 1;
  if ( i++ < n ) console.log(y);
  
  while ( i++ < n ) {
    const z = x + y ;
    x = y ;
    y = z ;
    console.log(z);
  }
    
}

fibonacci(10);
```